# Converting log-odds estimates from glmer table to odds-ratios

Tags: regression, logistic, interaction, odds-ratio, contrasts

I am trying to work out how to express the results of interaction contrasts between two categorical variables in a hierarchical logistic regression, one a two level variable `Studygroup` and the other a three-level variable `assessment_cat`. Thanks to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33709/interpreting-the-regression-output-from-a-mixed-model-when-interactions-between) excellent question and answer I have been able to work out how to put together the interactions by adding the coefficients estimates from the `glmer` table. However interpreting the output once the log odds have been exponentiated to odds ratios is more confusing.

This is the `glmer` table of coefficients

```
                                          Estimate Std..Error    z.value     Pr...z..
(Intercept)                             0.72369704  0.5638152  1.2835712 0.1992920165
Studygroupintervention                 -0.06223667  0.1335099 -0.4661579 0.6411025172
assessment_cat2                         1.68103031  0.4424892  3.7990310 0.0001452629
assessment_cat3                        -0.39206346  0.3181081 -1.2324851 0.2177679252
Studygroupintervention:assessment_cat2 -0.80185985  0.6182360 -1.2970124 0.1946269037
Studygroupintervention:assessment_cat3  1.03723190  0.4367688  2.3747849 0.0175591776
```

I have attempted to draw up a log-odds table in the same manner as in the answer above (applied to regular regression), so that each cell has a corresponding estimate comprised of the additive combination of the values from the glmer output. The int-cont column is the difference in log-odds between the intervention and control groups for each level of `assessment_cat`

```
              Control   Intervention    Int-Cont
Category 1     0.7237        0.66146    -0.06224
Category 2     2.4047        1.54063    -0.86407
Category 3     0.3332        1.30663     0.97343
```

My question is, can I just exponentiate these values to get estimates of odds-ratios, like so?

```
1. Cont/Cat1 vs Cont/Cat2: 0.724 vs 2.405 = +1.68; Odds-Ratio 5.365556 
2. Cont/Cat1 vs Cont/Cat3: 0.724 vs 0.322 = -0.392; Odds-Ratio 0.6757041
3. Cont/Cat2 vs Cont/Cat3: 2.405 vs 0.322 = -2.07; Odds-Ratio 0.1261858
4. Cont/Cat1 vs Int/Cat1: 0.724 vs 0.662 = -0.064; Odds-Ratio 0.938005
5. Cont/Cat2 vs Int/Cat2: 2.405 vs 1.541 = -0.864; Odds-Ratio 0.4214728
6. Cont/Cat3 vs Int/Cat3: 0.333 vs 1.307 = 0.973; Odds-Ratio 2.64587
```

and like so for the interaction contrasts?

```
7. 4 vs 5: -0.064 vs -0.864 = -0.801; Odds-Ratio 0.4488799 
8. 4 vs 6: -0.064 vs +0.973 = 1.03; Odds-Ratio 2.820742 
9. 5 vs 6: -0.864 vs +0.973 = 1.839; Odds-Ratio 6.290245
```

Or do the sort of additions used to derive interaction contrasts with standard regression tables break-down when converting from log-odds to odds-ratios?